# Is every sigma algebra the sigma algebra generated by some function?

Tags: measure-theory

Given measurable spaces $(A, \mathcal A)$, $(B,\mathcal B)$ and a measurable function $f:A\to B$, we can define the sigma algebra generated by $f$ on $A$, $\sigma(f)=f^{-1}(\mathcal B)\subseteq \mathcal A$. Is *every* sub sigma algebra of $\mathcal A$ realizable as the sigma algebra generated by a function $f$ into *some* measurable space $B$?

I believe the answer is yes, but I'd like for someone to check my construction.

> Let $\mathcal A'\subseteq \mathcal A$. Let $f(a)$ be the "indicator function" $\textbf 1_a:\mathcal A'\to\{0,1\}$ such that $\textbf 1_a(X)=1\iff a\in X$. In other words, $f(a)$ is the complete description of which sets in $\mathcal A'$ contain $a$. Then we can define $B=f(A)\subseteq\{0,1\}^{\mathcal A'}$ and $\mathcal B = \{f(X)\mid X\in\mathcal A'\}$, which I believe is a sigma algebra.

If this is correct, is there perhaps a simpler construction?

Comment: I don't believe you have well-defined $f$ at all. Are you defining $f$ on $A$ or $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: Also I think your question has a trivial answer if you are allowed to take any $(B, \mathcal{B})$ since you can simply take $(A,\mathcal{A})
 = (B,\mathcal{B})$ then take $f:A \to A$ to be the identity.

Comment: @ProjectBook $f$ is defined on $A$ (it's defined on points, not sets).

Comment: However, I messed up the definition of $f$. In particular, I made no mention of the sub-sigma algebra of $\mathcal A$ that I was aiming for. I'll edit the question.

Comment: So you are asking for a fixed $(B,\mathcal B)$ such that for *every* sub-sigma algebra of $\mathcal A$ there is a function $f:A\to B$ that generates this sub-sigma algebra?

Comment: @drhab No. I doubt that's even possible. The answer you just deleted was correct, and I've been trying to think about what kind of extra criterion could be put on the problem to rule out trivial examples like that. Perhaps I could add the condition $f(\mathcal A)=\mathcal B$, which I think might be true for my example. But that would be a separate question, of course.

Comment: Your construction is at least confusing. If $f(a)$ is a function on $\mathcal A'$ then you better write $f_a$ to avoid confusion. Then further what is $f(A)$? Do you mean (in your terms) $f(a)(A)$? Is there any difference between $f(a)$ and $1_a$? If not then why not consistently use of one of them? It is unclear to me what you are aiming at.

Comment: Every $a\in A$ has an "$\mathcal A'$-signature", the description of which sets in $\mathcal A'$ it belongs to. $f(a)$ is that signature, and $B$ is the set of all signatures. $\mathcal B$ is essentially the cylinder sigma algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathcal A_0\subseteq\mathcal A$ be a $\sigma$-algebra.

Let $\langle B,\mathcal B\rangle=\langle A,\mathcal A_0\rangle$.

Then the identity function $\mathsf{id}:A\to B$ prescribed by $a\mapsto a$ is well defined and measurable.

This function generates $\mathcal A_0$ because $\mathsf{id}^{-1}(\mathcal A_0)=\mathcal A_0$.